# Stuck on a limits problem

Tags: limits, functions

I'm having some trouble with this one limit, here's what I have so far:

$$
\lim_{t\to2}\frac{t^3 + 3t^2 - 12t + 4}{t^3 - 4t} 
= \lim_{t\to2} \frac{t(t^2 + 3t - 12) + 4}{t(t^2 - 4)}
= \lim_{t\to2} \frac{t(t^2 + 3t - 12) + 4}{t((t + 2)(t - 2))} = \frac{0}{0}
$$

This needs to be solved without L'Hôpital's rule. 
I'm stuck with the above, and I can't seem to continue solving it.

Any help (preferably well-explained) is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$t^3+3t^2-12t+4=(t-2)(t^2+5t-2)$$
and
$$t^3-4t=t(t-2)(t+2),$$
you'll have
$$\lim_{t\to 2}\frac{t^3+3t^2-12+4}{t^3-4t}=\lim_{t\to 2}\frac{t^2+5t-2}{t(t+2)}=\frac{2^2+5\cdot 2-2}{2\cdot (2+2)}.$$

Comment: How'd you get the first one ? $$t^3 + 3t^2 - 12t + 4 = (t-2)(t^2 + 5t - 2)$$

Comment: @IlijaBoshkov: First, you know it has $(t-2)$ because $2^3+3\cdot 2^2-12\cdot 2+4=0$. Second, you can get $t^2+5t-2$ by dividing the left hand side by $t-2$.

Comment: Sorry I'm just not seeing the $t-2$ in $2^3 + 3 * 2^2 - 12 * 2 + 4$

Comment: @IlijaBoshkov: This is because Factor theorem. see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for elaborating your answer.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{t^3 + 3t^2 - 12t + 4}{t^3 - 4t} =1+\frac{(3t-2)(t-2)}{t(t-2)(t+2)}$$

We can safely cancel $t-2$ as $t-2\ne0$ as $t\ne2$ as $t\to2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Your evaluation shows that the numerator and denominator both have root $\,\color{#c00}{t = 2}.\,$ Thus being $ $ *polynomials* $ $ in $\,t,\,$ the Factor Theorem implies  $ $ that they both  have a factor  $\,\color{#c00}{t-2}.\,$ Cancelling this common factor from the fraction yields a limit of *determinate* form.